# How to Custom Base Attribute using PXCustomizeBaseAttribute for DAC

Tags: acumatica

I need to migrate open Cases data from old system which listed on Excel file to Acumatica CRM using import scenario. After enabling the field by customizing the attribute and checking the loading result, the Date Reported field are still loaded with current date. After further checking, the problem can be solved by overriding DAC declaration. Since i am new to Acumatica framework, kindly need advice about how to Custom Base Attribute of the following field which declared on CRCase:

```
#region CreatedDateTime

public abstract class createdDateTime : IBqlField { }

protected DateTime? _CreatedDateTime;
[PXDBCreatedDateTimeUtc(InputMask = "g")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Date Reported", Enabled = false)]
public virtual DateTime? CreatedDateTime
{
    get
    {
        return this._CreatedDateTime;
    }
    set
    {
        this._CreatedDateTime = value;
        _timeResolution = null;
    }
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreatedDateTime field is a system audit field.  I do not recommend altering the behavior of audit fields.  They serve a specific purpose.

I suggest create a DateReported user field to your application, and importing your source data to that field.

If you must use CreatedDateTime, mostly likely have to override the attributes using the CacheAttached method, of your particular graph.  Again, I do not recommend altering the behavior of audit fields.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the response. the createddatetime also needed to calculate SLA aging. Funny things after import the data, for case which actually reported on 12 December 2015, the SLA date shows that the case will be due on 11 January 2016 while Date Reported is far in the future (28 Sep 2016). If it is need to usrField for backdated Date Reported, than the calculation of SLA date must be custom too, which I believe will be complex things to do.

Comment: problem solved by adding custom field "Date Raised" which then agreed by customer after negotiating that Date Reported is System Audited field. SLA due date for existing case will be calculated based on this custom field and will be monitored using specific generic inquiry. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I go with the idea that Date Reported is an system audited field and it is must not be altered. so, I create new custom field called "Date Raised" to input existing case date reported.